# Python selenium timeout exception without message when clicking

Tags: python, selenium

I want to search specific word in ScienceDirect and when is shows results I want to click 100 result per page at the bottom on page.

HTML code:

```
<a class="anchor" data-aa-region="srp-pagination-options" data-aa-name="srp-100-results-per-page" href="/search?qs=Python&amp;show=100"><span class="anchor-text">100</span></a>
```

And that's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.sciencedirect.com/")
assert "Science" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, "qs-searchbox-input")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("Python")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".data-aa-name[value='srp-100-results-per-page']"))
)
element.click()
driver.close()
```

And exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\pythonProject\selenium\count_cited.py", line 15, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
  File "X:\pythonProject\selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: In order to avoid an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) please clarify what your ultimate goal is, what information are you from that website and in what format.

Comment: It has timed out because the selector is wrong.  the "." is for a class....  there is no "class='data-aa-name..."  You want to target by attribute of "data-aa-name".  In XPATH that'd be something like //a[@data-aa-name='srp-100-results-per-page']  I don't use CSS selectors, but in CSS I think it'd be "a[data-aa-name='srp-100-results-per-page']"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for example this CSS selector:

```
 "div#srp-pagination-options li:nth-child(3)"
```